# horizontally displayed JSON data react card

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react ,I am fetching some json data and I would like to displayed them horizontally in bootstrap card,Whenever I tried ,it keeps displayed vertically .here is my code.

```
<div className="row"  >
<div className="col-md-4" >
<div className="card" >
             <img className="card-img-top" src={user.picture.large? ( user.picture.large) : ("http://appalachiantrail.org/images/default-source/default-album/trailfocus.jpg?sfvrsn=2")} />
               <div className="card-body" >
                 <h1 className="card-title">{user.name.first}</h1>
                   <h2 className="card-text">{user.id.value} </h2>
                     <h4 className="card-text">{user.email} </h4>
                     </div>
<br>
                     </br>

   </div>
</div>
```

this is what I want to achieve

[image: this is what I want to achieve]

See  [code here](https://codepen.io/abbeyjfitzgerald/pen/vgjwVN) of what I want to achieve,how do I replace those static column with my dynamic json response data ? Please advise

thanks

Comment: you have to you smonething like fetch/promise or axios is a npm bundle for json reqeusts.

Comment: yes,I did using axios . getusers()
{
  this.setState({loading:true})
 axios('https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=US&results=5')
   .then(response=>this.setState(
    {users:
      [...this.state.users, ...response.data.results],
      loading:false
      })

);
}

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting them inside a container with `display:flex` styling

```
<style>
.container{
   display:flex;
}
</style>
<div class="container"> 
  <div className="card-body" >
     <h1 className="card-title">{user.name.first}</h1>
     <h2 className="card-text">{user.id.value} </h2>
     <h4 className="card-text">{user.email} </h4>
  </div>
  <div className="card-body" >
     <h1 className="card-title">{user.name.first}</h1>
     <h2 className="card-text">{user.id.value} </h2>
     <h4 className="card-text">{user.email} </h4>
  </div>
  <div className="card-body" >
     <h1 className="card-title">{user.name.first}</h1>
     <h2 className="card-text">{user.id.value} </h2>
     <h4 className="card-text">{user.email} </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about fetching the data or displaying it successfully but about aligning your "cards" horizontally which is only CSS related.

It might be because of the bootstrap styles but if have your container like this...

```
<div className="card-container">
    <Card>...</Card>
    <Card>...</Card>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card-container {
    display: flex;
    ...
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 25%; (or however you want to size)
    ...
}
```

Everything should be horizontal with `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0):

This question is not specific enough.

The point of ReactJS is to serve data in an active state. Use Javascript to display and interact with the user.
In your situation you need to extract the display components from the example into your **React.Component** and utilize XHR(AJAX) request (probably using ext library **axios**).

Search for examples of these:

- [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)
- [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)
- [React List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)